# Mixing xsd:choice with xsd:any or xsd:sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have the following two (unchangeable) XML files with **same** namespace, which I need to create an XSD for:

pseudo-xml example #1:

```
<Project>
    <ProjectInformation/>
    <HistoryEntry/>
    <UserFiles/>
</Project>
```

pseudo-xml example #2:

```
<Project>
    <Installations/>
</Project>
```

Without the `HistoryEntry` and `UserFiles` element, I would use `xsd:choice` for `ProjectInformation` and `Installations`. But how can bring `HistoryEntry` and `UserFiles` element into the game?!

Is there a standard XSD mechanism that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unordered is overrated.  Just use `xs:sequence` rather than `xs:any` to avoid unique particle attribution violations in XSD 1.0:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Project">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ProjectInformation"/>
          <xs:element name="HistoryEntry"/>
          <xs:element name="UserFiles"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Installations"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that I can can mix sequence and element in choice.. Works for me now.